# Limit number of values in a field using MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

My collection has an array of values, but I'd like to retrieve only the last X.
Example:

```
db.collection.find({
   "array": [0,1,2,3,4,5]
})
```

And I'd like to query the last 3. How would I go about that?

I'm using MongoDB and this is meant for a Meteor application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/#proj._S_slice) operator.

```
db.collection.find( { /* filter */ }, { "array": { "$slice": -3 } } );
```