# using $slice operator i'm not able to get proper set of data ,

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have started creating a small chat application,since im using mongodb i started to implement with $slice for getting only latest 10 messages in my chat history. but the issue is that im not able get the latest set of data{10 messages},(data mismatch happens for every instance) . please any one help me out .

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: i want to get 10 set of values first and next i need other set of 10 values , in my chat history but ---> data mismatch happens  when i go for other set of 10 values

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limit number of values in a field using MongoDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34228375/limit-number-of-values-in-a-field-using-mongodb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to use a negative value to retrieve the latest elements.

From the [$slice](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/projection/slice/) docs:

> $slice accepts arguments in a number of formats, including negative values and arrays. Consider the following examples:
>
> ```
> db.posts.find( {}, { comments: { $slice: 5 } } )
> ```
>
> Here, $slice selects the first five items in an array in the comments field.
>
> ```
> db.posts.find( {}, { comments: { $slice: -5 } } )
> ```
>
> This operation returns the last five items in array.

Comment: I want to get the latest 10 set of values ..db.posts.find( {}, { comments: { $slice: -10} } )   but im getting the latest 10 values, if i want to get the other set of 10 values , data mismatch happens .